# DatePicker inside textfield

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker

Is there any way to connect textfield with datepicker in layout?

Like this

[image: datepickerMD3]

solutions with onFocusChangelistener and clickListeners, in my opinion, are bad. maybe there is a convenient way?

Comment: Could't You just use `DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener` ?

Comment: @Sabriael, So I need to make a text field with a date picker in xml. I understand how to do some attributes:`endIcon`,`helperText`.
But how to implement the appearance of the calendar - I do not know